# MySQL: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'status' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `ItemType` in my database which has the following structure:
[image]
When I try to add a new item to it, it gives an error of `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'status' in 'field list'`

The query I used is:

```
INSERT INTO itemtype(itemType, bookType, suggestedPrice, status, cashreceipt_cashdisbursment)
    VALUES ('Death Certificate', 1, 2500.00, 1, 1);
```

Clearly there is a `status` column in my table, so why is MySQL complaining about it being missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/teXXTDK7ry6DrwSdtYhHu6/1).

Comment: Do you have any trigger to this table?

Answer (score 0):

@Donovan Keating You miss details, in the request try this :

```
INSERT INTO itemtype(itemType, bookType, suggestedPrice, status, details, cashreceipt_cashdisbursment) VALUES ('Death Certificate', 1, 2500.00, 1, 'NULL', 1);
```

Comment: I don't think details being missing is relevant to my problem.

Comment: @Donovan Keating are you sure Status haven't got capitalized characters or a space adding by error look at plz :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that after `status` the next column is `details` that has a `TEXT` datatype:

so, before `cashreceipt_cashdisbursment` you should add either `NULL` or a text value:

```
INSERT INTO itemtype(itemType, bookType, suggestedPrice, `status`, details, cashreceipt_cashdisbursment) VALUES ('Death Certificate', 1, 2500.00, 1, NULL, 1);
```

Also, please note that `status` is a MySQL keyword, so you should wrap its name in backticks.

Comment: do you have any chance to rename that column name? Since it is a MySQL keyword it could be better to rename it. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#table-keywords-5.7-detailed) for further references.

Comment: I mean something like item_status

Comment: I have a trigger for this table. I'll update my post as soon as possible.

Comment: I've found the problem, I used status in a function without declaring.

Comment: `status` is a MySQL *keyword* but it is not reserved.  This is easily checked:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you have one of the column names and the table are same. itemType is your table name and the same name is repeated for a column name right after the table name in the insert query. Maybe this could help at a time when other solutions herein did not work. Besides the table name is not case sensitive here which could be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. Just turn off and turn on your database and server.